# android accelerometer accuracy is extremely poor

Tags: android, sensors

Wrote a simple program that prints out accelerometer output.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

It turns out that:

1. The accelerometer output is always set to "lowest" as determined by:

   ```
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
     if (collectingData){  
        accelPrecision.setText("accelerometer accuracy: " + accuracy);
     }
   }
   ```
2. The actual accelerometer readings are very inaccurate - about 2%-5% fluctuations even when it's resting on the table

as far as I can tell it's the same problem on Nexus S, Nexus One and G1

Any idea how it could be made mode accurate / what sets a

Comment: 2%-5% accuracy for an accelerometer is pretty good.

Comment: Accelerometer accuracy is hardware-dependent. That given, it's not an Android (software) issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter. You are looking at raw data so of course its going to fluctuate. Something like a [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average) or a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average_%28finance%29) will suffice.

Comment: Thanks. But why is my idle Nexus S always reports accuracy as "0" which is (according to the dev docs) "SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE" - The values returned by this sensor cannot be trusted, calibration is needed or the environment doesn't allow readings